# How can I serialize System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity?

Tags: .net, windows, serialization, acl

I am working on small scale deployment system for our in-house software that manages backups of several kinds of data. Part of the task is to backup certain folders, and I would like to backup the ACLs applied to those folders so that on restore the files still work as expected.

Prototyping some code, I have tried using .NET's built-in XmlSerializer but to no avail.

Here is the example code:

```
public static byte[] SerializeFileACL(string path)
{
    var acl = File.GetAccessControl(path, AccessControlSections.All);

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        _fileSerializer.Serialize(ms, acl);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

However this returns the same 143 bytes no matter what file I try it on. Is there a good way of serializing ACLs using .NET facilities? What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: Yes, I am aware that ACLs may not be applicable to other computers. This is not an issue for this project.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated data? Can you post it?

Comment: It's just an empty .XML file. I'm guessing the class just doesn't support XML serialization, however I can't seem to find any good way to save it beyond manually scrapping the entire File/DirectoryClass.

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DirectorySecurity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply call the `NativeObjectSecurity.Persist` method [as described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb3w0s75.aspx) to serialize this object. As one person mentioned the object does not contain a `SerializableAttribute` and thus you cannot serialize the object graph in the friendly way.

Answer (score 3):

The `XmlSerializer` only saves public members of an object - it won't serialize any of the members of the DirectorySecurity class because it doesn't have any public ones.

There are other serializers which can save non-public members (e.g., the `BinaryFormatter`), but they require the types themselves to declare themselves as serializable (i.e., using the `[Serializable]` attribute), and the `DirectorySecurity` class doesn't have this attribute. So you can't use direct serialization to save it - you'll need to extract the information you want to persist and store it instead of the original object.

Comment: Your answer is good too but Michael's highlights the solution as well. Upvoted :)